# How to manage a Django Rest Framework codebase when API versions change?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, versioning

There's plenty of topics about api versioning. But many don't discuss how versioning affects the codebase. How do you go about managing the codebase when the version changes? Examples would be appreciated.

**Example: codebase for version 1**

Default versioning: NamespaceVersioning

Model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharFiedl(max_length=20)
    pages=models.IntegerField()
```

view:

```
class BookView(views.ViewSet):
    def List(self, request):
        books = Books.objects.all()
        return Response(BookSerializer(books, many=True).data)
```

serializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'pages']
```

What would the code and folder structure for version 2 look like when breaking changes are introduced?

Answer (score 0):

Through python packages for example `views.py` can be divided into separate `<name>_<version>.py` files. Then depending on the desired import effect if the url imports must stay the same they can be imported in the `__init__.py` file as `from <name>_<version> import *`

Let's say you have `View1` and `View2` in `views.py`; You can put the implementation code in the separate files in a folder called `views` with `__init__.py` where you import as above - `from file1 import *`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So that means code duplication. For the sake of simplicity, let’s say we have two django apps. App 1 introduces breaking changes and is versioned to version 2. Do you change the version of app 2 to keep consistency or leave it at version 1?

Comment: well breaking changes almost always mean code duplication if you want to keep old version working.

Comment: well that depends what you want to achieve. But if you don't want to use App1_v2 in the App2_v1 what is the point of using App1_v2 ? If you can't update everything in one go and need 2 versions working at the same time (Strangler Pattern) then you need to duplicate.

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. You have App1 v1 and v2 and App2 depends on App1 ? If yes then why bother with App1 v2 if you won't use it here?

Comment: They’re independent of each other. The question is more about design style. Is it a good idea to keep the version similar across all apps even when app 2 doesn’t introduce breaking changes?

Comment: You can keep app2 at version 1 as long as you want, things that need app1 v2 use app1 v2 and that is all.  If app1 v2 introduced breaking changes and has few endpoints/urls used by front well they will use v2 but the rest of apps don't have if the rest of apps work at v1 keep them at v1 .

Comment: You updated app1 and urls have probably /v1/ /v2/ the new front or new functionalites use v2 old ones use v1 ? If the use of v2 doesn't affect other apps no point in changing them. App1 is separate from other let's say app1 is for operating on pictures, you bump to v2 now it can operate on jpg but not on png. you give link to v1 and old views and link to v2 with new views. Two separate files two separate views. But the rest of the apps can stay the same.